# How to create overlay bar plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

While updating some of my earlier code to use pandas.DataFrame, I'm got stuck with following problem...

This is the reference plot that my original code would create:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(1, 25)
b = a
c = [x+2 for x in b]
d = [x*2 for x in c]

plt.bar(a, d)
plt.bar(a, c)
plt.bar(a, b)
plt.show()
```

[image: reference plot]

Problem definition:

I would like to create this very same plot using pandas.DataFrame built in functionality. To be precise, only the bars placement is relevant, I'm not interested in the formatting/labeling of axis ticks.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.set_index('a', inplace=True)

df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: first pandas plot]

Neither, default pandas bar-plot (shown above) nor adding `stacked=True` option (see below), produced the desired result.

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: second pandas plot]

Unfortunately,`overlay=True` option does not exist.

Is there another (preferably elegant) way to achieve the desired result?

If nothing else is available, I will just modify the pandas.DataFrame values (i.e. subtract the columns from each other) and then use `stacked=True` option. Before, I implement that, I'm looking forward to see your suggestions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `ax` parameter with the value returned by [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html), like this:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()
df.d.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, color='red')
df.c.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, color='green')
df.b.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, color='blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following.
If this is your data:

```
a = range(1, 25)
b = [x+1 for x in b]
c = [x+2 for x in b]
d = [x*2 for x in c]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Then call plot directly on your dataframe. Then you can also use the `stacked = True` argument. Like this:

```
df[["a", "b", "c", "d"]].plot(x="d", kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Here a  picture:

[image: picture]